# How to place an "Ex." item at the beginning of an itemized list in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, itemize, context-mkiv

I created a macro which displays an list of numbers, where readers can write in their answers to a question.

```
\def\answers{
    \startitemize[n]
        \docursive{3}{\item}
    \stopitemize
 }
```

In the document, it might appear like this:

```
What do you think of pizza? Write three sentences.
    1.
    2.
    3.
```

I need to add an example answer, just before this list, to help readers to better know what kind of answers will be okay.

```
What do you think of pizza? Write three sentences.
    Ex. I think pizza is so-so.
    1.
    2.
    3.
```

The macro could be typed as `\answers{I think pizza is so-so.}` and "Ex." and the following text would take identical formatting found in other lists in the document.

Is there any way to define a place for "Ex." at the beginning of an itemized list in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\sym`.

```
\setupitemize[width=2em, itemalign=flushright, distance=0.5ex]
\starttext

\startitemize[n]
  \sym{Ex.} Example
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]